# Powershell Scheduled Tasks WIth Multiple Triggers

Tags: powershell

I am trying to build a Powershell script that can be run across about 10,000 devices, to create a scheduled task to run every 2 hours to check on a pair of troublesome services. These services are put in place by the vendor of the software.

My current code that is more copy/paste from various places, errors on the ScheduledTaskTriggers.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, critiques welcome.

```
# Define the name of the task
$taskName = "Check Automate Services"
# Create a new task that runs a PowerShell script
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "-Command `"If((Get-Service LTService).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Service LTService }
If((Get-Service LTSvcMon).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Service LTSvcMon }`""
# Define the trigger for the task to run every 2 hours
$trigger1 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 12:00am -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Hours 2) -RepetitionDuration (New-TimeSpan -Days 365)
# Add a missed task action to run the task immediately
$trigger2 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn -ExecutionTimeLimit (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 15)
$trigger2.SetEnabled($false)
# Combine the triggers into an array
$triggers = @($trigger1, $trigger2)
# Register the task with the Task Scheduler
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $action -Trigger $triggers -Settings (New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -MissedTaskHandling "RunImmediately") -RunLevel Highest
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: I would check Windows Event Viewer for errors.